# How to validate my email-Id field?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have used this regular expression.
This script should not allow this:  **________**@domain.com

Please help me to avoid this issue.

```
"email": {
           // HTML5 compatible email regex ( http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#    e-mail-state-%28type=email%29 )
           "regex": /^(([^<>()[\]\\.*+,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@[^-]((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
           "alertText": "* Ex: user@domain.com"
         },
```

Comment: It took 5 seconds to find this solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

A comment points this out : "This regex eliminates valid, in-use emails. Do not use. Google for "RFC822" or "RFC2822" to get a proper regex"

Comment: thank u softy,, give me valid regex

Comment: i need at least 1 character or number before @ symbol. how to change the above regex for thhis?

Comment: post a sample email address. So you want to match the address which has atleast one number present before @.

Comment: my script should not allow _____@domain.com and it should not affect existing condition

Comment: If you are targeting to only HTML5 browsers ( obviously you can use Modernizer.js to make it compatible for others), then, you can directly use <input type="email" />, no need to validate email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a lookahead to match the email address which has atleast one number or an alphabet present before @.

```
(?=^[^@]*[\dA-Za-z][^@]*@)^(([^<>()[\]\\.*+,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@[^-]((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/46)

This ensures that there must be atleast a number and an alphabet present  before  the `@` symbol.

```
(?=^[^@]*\d[^@]*@)(?=^[^@]*[A-Za-z][^@]*@)^(([^<>()[\]\\.*+,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@[^-]((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/45)

Comment: @Unihedron he wants to match the addresses which has atleast one number before @

Comment: thanks. its working fine for number. but either number or alphabet character can be there before @ symbol.

Comment: Wow super thambi kalakkitta

Comment: Anna, yentha regexa neenga yethirpaakkureenga, first ah second ah :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can like this : \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

/^([\w-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([\w-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$/;

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like **[A-za-z]** at beggining of this expression..
So that you must enter at least a single alphapet before _ ...

```
"email": {                 
                    "regex": /^ [A-Za-z](([^<>()[\]\\.*+,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@[^-]((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                    "alertText": "* Ex: user@domain.com"
                },
```